# Not able to return the array after being populated by the async request inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to return the array which is being async populated after every `foreach` loop. But when I return, I get only `undefined`.

Below is the code block:

```
var navigateAndFetchPages = function (data) {
  var countryPages = [];
  data.forEach(function (val) {
    Rq(val.esomar_url)
      .then(function (data) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(data),
              pages_elem = $('.mt0.mb0-5.pt0').find('a').not('.active');
          countryPages.push({country_name: val.country_name, links: pages_elem});
    })
  });
  return countryPages;
};


var scraper = {
    extract: function (dir) {
        return landingPage(dir)
            .then(function (countries) {
                return navigateAndFetchPages(countries)
            })
            .then(function (p) {
                p()
            })
            .catch();
    }
};
```

Comment: _"But when I return, I get only `undefined`"_ Where is a value returned from `navigateAndFetchPages`?

Comment: sorry, added the return value.. And i know the value is being returned before the async proc could complete.. But I can't also return within the foreach block.. Now i'm stuck what to do..

Comment: Do you need to return the array directly like that, or can you structure your code to use a promise or a callback function? (As per "normal" async processing.)

Comment: the arguments that the `navigateAndFetchPages` function receiving are an array of urls which i need to traverse to get links which will be returned in an array .. I can return the array directly so that i can chain it in my main  function from where `navigateAndFetchPages` is being called.

Updated the code with the callee.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1435132

Answer (score 1):

First things first, please indent your code properly -- it's much easier to follow!

Second, you need to embrace the asynchronicity of your code. `Rq`, presumably, is an asynchronous function: that makes the whole operation asynchronous. That means that `navigateAndFetchPages` needs to return promises, rather than trying to return the data.

The simple way to do this is with `Array#map`.

```
var navigateAndFetchPages = function(data) {
  return data.map(function(val) {
    return Rq(val.esomar_url).then(function(data) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data),
            pages_elem = $('.mt0.mb0-5.pt0').find('a').not('.active');
        return {
          country_name: val.country_name,
          links: pages_elem
        };
      })
  });
};
```

The result of a call to `navigateAndFetchPages` will now be an array of promises.

You can wait for them all to complete with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(navigateAndFetchPages(data)).then(function(result) {
  // result is an array of objects containing your data
});
```

Your updated question shows that this is itself called in a chain of promises. This is easy to deal with:

```
var scraper = {
    extract: function (dir) {
        return landingPage(dir)
            .then(function (countries) {
                return Promise.all(navigateAndFetchPages(countries));
            })
            .then(function (p) {
                p()
            })
            .catch();
    }
};
```

You *could* put `Promise.all` inside the `navigateAndFetchPages` function, but I wouldn't, in case you need to access individual pages' data in future. It's your API, though, so that's up to you.

Comment: sorry for the indentation .. i was in a haste to get the answer.. the `Rq` is an instance of `request-promise`

Comment: @guest271314 Good spot: fixed.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes... Again, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can substitute `.map()`, `Promise.all()` for `.forEach()`, `return` object from `.then()` which will be included within resulting array at `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()`

```
var navigateAndFetchPages = function(data) {

  return Promise.all(data.map(function(val) {
    return Rq(val.esomar_url)
      .then(function(data) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data),
          pages_elem = $('.mt0.mb0-5.pt0').find('a').not('.active');
          return {
            country_name: val.country_name,
            links: pages_elem
          };
      });
  }));

};

navigateAndFetchPages
.then(function(countryPages) {
  // do stuff with `countryPages`
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```